# CakePHP - Know the time and date users have logged into my application

Tags: cakephp

Is it possible to know the time and date users have logged in my application or do I need to store this information in my User's table myself? Just wondering if the Authentication procedure has any kind of logs already in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for sth like http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/09/17/keeping-track-of-usersguests/

Basically, a table where you trigger an update with each page visit (or with every x one for performance). the created timestamp for a specific session id will tell you when they logged in. last_page_url and clicked_from where they currently are and where they came from etc.

Answer (score 1):

yes you have to store login information in separate table so you can make track of user login history.

there is no in built functionality provide by cakephp framework.